# How to manage user login and logout state in React Js with redux and cookie,localstorage?

Tags: reactjs, redux, cookies, local-storage, react-router-dom

I have a login functionality in my reactjs app, when user login my app im storing its refresh and access token in my redux store my initial store of user is
data:{
isLoggedIn:false,
userData:null
}
after login i am saving userData and setting isLoggedin:true ,and also i am storing accesstoken in my browser cookie also
Now i have to manage the userData with respect to cookie ,cookie expiration time is one hour
so I have to create a middleware for every api call to validate cookie from my browser and if its expired then create a new cookie and store it to browser cookie , i have api/refreshToken api to create new token.. my refresh token expiry is 24hour so i also want to check is refresh token is expired then user will automatically logout if cookie is null

Every time i am any api after some time of login i am getting unauthorized error so i want to update my cookie before any api call.
And also want to restrict routes if user is not logged,
and i have to manage my redux store according to cookie and refresh token validations..

```
  const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer);

  const isUserLoggedIn = userInfo.userData.isLoggedIn;



  <Route
          path="/"
          element={isUserLoggedIn ? <DashBoardLayout /> : <LoginPage />}
        >
          {isUserLoggedIn ? (
            <Route index element={<Overview />} />
          ) : (
            <Route index element={<LoginPage />} />
          )}
```

i have used persist redux to store in local storage ,

Answer (score 2):

Create A high order function for restricting the routes.

```
import React from "react";
import secureLocalStorage from "react-secure-storage";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateComponent = () => {
  const auth = JSON.parse(secureLocalStorage.getItem("adminInfo"));
  console.log("auth", auth);
  return auth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default PrivateComponent;
```

same like this and wrap this component on the routes.

Comment: You dont need to wrap react secure storage with JSON.parse, the library is capable of remembering the object types